# Getting neural network inputs back from outputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, deep-learning

I am building a neural network using keras with same neurons number in each layer and same activation function (LeakyReLU)in order to get the input back from the outputs. I know that is mathematically possible and I can found that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49887453/predicting-neural-network-input-from-its-output) also.

That works with 1 or 2 layered neural networks but on deeper ones there is much difference between the given input and the one calculated from the output.

This is my neural network implementation:

```
input_dim = 256
LR = 0.25
# create encoder model

input_plain = Input(shape=(input_dim,))

encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(input_plain)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(input_dim, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(LR)(encoded)

encoder = Model(input_plain, encoded)

encoded = encoder.predict(x_test)
```

And this inverse leaky relu function:

```
def LeakyReLU_inv(alpha,x):
  output = np.copy(x)
  output[ output < 0 ] /= alpha
  return output
```

And this is how I get the original inputs from outputs:

```
encoder_weights= encoder.get_weights()
decoder_weights = []

for w in encoder_weights:
  decoder_weights.append((np.linalg.inv(w)))

decoder_weights.reverse()

x = encoded
for w in decoder_weights:
  x = LeakyReLU_inv(LR,x) 
  x = np.dot(x,w)
```

I have built a smaller neural network with two layer and implemented the same logic and it worked:

```
input_plain = Input(shape=(3,))

encoded = Dense(3, use_bias=False)(input_plain)
encoded = LeakyReLU(0.25)(encoded)
encoded = Dense(3, use_bias=False)(encoded)
encoded = LeakyReLU(0.25)(encoded)
encoder = Model(input_plain, encoded)

W1 = encoder.get_weights()[0]
W2 = encoder.get_weights()[1]
Z1 = np.dot(X,W1)
Y_calc1 = LeakyReLU_(0.25,Z1)
Z2 = np.dot(Y_calc1,W2)
Y_calc2 = LeakyReLU_(0.25,Z2)
Y_calc2_inv = LeakyReLU_inv(0.25,Y)
Z_inv2 = np.dot(Y_calc2_inv,np.linalg.inv(W2))
Y_calc1_inv = LeakyReLU_inv(0.25,Z_inv2)
x= np.dot(Y_calc1_inv,np.linalg.inv(W1))
```

Note that I have implemented LeakyReLU_ as shown:

```
def LeakyReLU_(alpha,x):
  output = np.copy(x)Y_calc1
  output[ output < 0 ] *= alpha
  return output
```

What I am doing wrong in the first deeper neural network that get wrong calculated input not correct like the two-layered neural network?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is too much of work to achieve what you want. I bet what you are looking for is an `Autoencoder`. Autoencoders are used to generate the exact same input at the output layer while processing the input through a set of encoding and decoding layers.

The idea is to reduce the dimension of the input at the end of the encoding layers and still use the dimensionally reduced tensor to effectively reconstruct the input at the output layer with a minimal loss of information.

Following is an autoencoder I built for reconstructing the input image at the output layer.

```
def autoencoder(inputs):
    # encoder
    # 32 x 32 x 1   ->  16 x 16 x 64
    # 16 x 16 x 64  ->  8 x 8 x 32
    # 8 x 8 x 32  ->  4 x 4 x 16
    # 4  x 4  x 16  ->  1 x 1 x 100
    conv1 = lays.conv2d(inputs, 64, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    conv2 = lays.conv2d(conv1, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    conv3 = lays.conv2d(conv2, 16, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    conv4 = lays.conv2d(conv3, 100, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    # decoder
    # 1 x 1 x 100   ->  4 x 4 x 16 
    # 4 x 4 x 16    ->  16 x 16 x 32
    # 16 x 16 x 32   ->  32 x 32 x 64
    # 32 x 32 x 64  ->  64 x 64 x 1
    # dconv1 = lays.conv2d_transpose(conv4, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    latent_ph = tf.placeholder_with_default(conv4, [None, 1, 1, 100], name="latent_ph")
    dconv1 = lays.conv2d_transpose(latent_ph, 16, [5, 5], stride=4, padding='SAME')
    dconv2 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv1, 32, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    dconv3 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv2, 64, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME')
    dconv4 = lays.conv2d_transpose(dconv3, 1, [5, 5], stride=2, padding='SAME', activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
    # W_conv1 = weights([5, 5, 1, 64])
    # conv1 = conv2d(inputs, W_conv1, stride=(2,2))


    return dconv4, latent_ph, conv4
```

`tf.placeholder_with_default()` allows you to feed a tensor externally in testing time. So if you have a reduced format of an input, you could feed the reduced tensor to `tf.placeholder_with_default()` tensor and observe the output.

Coming back to your question, it doesn't matter if it's a deep network, a shallow network, a CNN, a fully connected NN, it should work when you implement one of these autoencoders. The only change you will have to make is that to make the `labels = inputs`.

Comment: I have tried autoencoders but the problem that the dataset is almost random so it will give a great error therefor.